# Command in task definition causes exception

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Originally in  a `Dockerfile` I use

```
 CMD python /app/src/main.py
```

to start a process in my docker container. It works as expected.

I am now in the process of deploying these docker images to the aws ecs.

I want to move this `CMD` out of the Dockerfile and put it as part of the task definition, because I suppose it will offer me more flexibility.

[image]

However when the docker container is spinned up, it emits this exception:

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"python
/app/src/main.py\": stat python /app/src/main.py: no such file or directory"
```

Apparently ecs treats the CMD parameter as if it refers to a single file.

I have tried to define the command as a list i.e. `["python", " /app/src/main.py"]` but it just raised a different error: `container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"[\\\"python\\\"\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Comment: It looks like this is more of an ECS issue rather than a docker one ...and whatever you are invoking python to, can't find the interpreter

Comment: Try defining the command as `python,/app/src/main.py`. Looks weird, but this is what I see in our task definitions that we converted from `docker-compose.yml` files using the [ecs-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I need to put the command as a comma delimited string i.e.

`python,/app/src/main.py`

Answer (score 0):

We are using Terraform, where the task definition was defined in JSON format. There, command is a JSON array, containing each part of the command as an element:

```json
{
  ...,
  "command" : ["python3", "/app/src/main.py"],
}
```